# Stuck with git commits I didn't mean to do

Tags: git, github, version-control

Somehow, when I added a repo I accidentally locally merged branch `production` into `new_vagrant` (commit `b267acd`).

I tried to fix this by changing which branch `production` tracks against so that it was again `production` instead of `new_vagrant` (commit `f9490c5`).

Thinking I had things back to the way they should be, I created a new branch off production to begin doing my work. Finished, then committed and pushed `244126c` to remote.

Now every time I try to switch to `production` and pull the latest changes from remote `production` branch, I see my working copy load up with uncommitted files even though I never did any work on the `production` branch. I tried doing a hard reset to `9edeb28`, but that didn't fix it. I still see I need to push some commits to `production`.

So I tried reversing the commits `b267acd`, but I just get the error `Commit b267acd is a merge but no -m option was given`. Same error with `f9490c5`.

Screenshot of my tree for context:
[image: messed up]

How do I undo this mess so I can sync successfully with the latest production changes?

Using SourceTree for most of my git work, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your local `production` look like the remote production, then you should just hard reset it. Note that this will discard ALL local state on the local `production` branch.

```
git checkout production
git reset --hard origin/production
```

Comment: That did the trick! Strange though, that when I tried this in SourceTree it didn't have the same cleansing effect as when done from the command line. What about those two merge commits I didn't mean to do? They still show up in git history. Could they cause problems in the future?

Comment: @eComEvo, As long as the merge commits are not part of the history of any branch, they will not harm you. They simply exist because they haven't yet been garbage collected.